# change dropbox selective sync while dropbox isn't running

Tags: sync, dropbox

I've added a largish folder to my Dropbox, but don't want to sync it to a computer that doesn't have dropbox running all the time.

I can start dropbox, then tell it not to sync that folder, but it'll likely start downloading it before I finish the command. I'd prefer to tell it not to sync that particular folder BEFORE I start drobox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

1. Turn Dropbox on, but pause all synchronisation.
2. Set the folder to not sync.
3. Turn Dropbox sync back on.

Alternatively, you could move the folder out of the Dropbox folder before turning Dropbox on.

Comment: yes, pausing immediately after turning on would work fairly well. I'm using the command line interface, so can do that almost instantly (:

Answer (score 2):

You could disconnect from your network before starting Dropbox. Then start Dropbox and make your changes.